# How to make a AJAX request while a tab is not open

Tags: ajax, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, offlineapps

I am working on offline app for chrome and wondering if there is any way to sync data that is queued up while offline and sync back in when I go back to online even without needing to keep the tab open.

Offline Gmail App for Chrome does that. when I send an email while offline and close the tab, then when I get back to online this email is sent. I would like to know if there is any chrome extension or some sort to accomplish this task.

any suggestions are welcome.
thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a [background.html](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/background_pages.html) page. In it you can run any JavaScript that you want and have it sync data silently in the background.